# Replacing single words with re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex

Spoiler: Yes this is an assignment. It is solved, but for personal interest I want to know the below.

So at the moment working with a syntax marker for an assignment, in which we input a file, and using a dictionary of regexes, colour them (keywords) accordingly.

Having some issues, though.

```
for i in iterations:
    pass
```

in this above line, using a regex
`r'(\t*for.*in.*?:.?)'` will work, but it will colour the entire line. While that is allowed, I would really like for it to only mark `for/in`.

Trying with `r'(\bfor\b|\bin\b)'` is not being kind, nor `r'(for)'`, or r'(\s*for\s*)'.

I read the whole code into one string and use re.sub() to replace all occurences with `colour + r'\1' + colour_end` where colour specifies colour sequences.

Comment: Use `r'^(\t*)(for)(.*)(in)(.*?:.?)'` and replace with `$1<color>$2</color>$3<color>$4</color>$5`

Comment: Should mention this above (will edit), but all regexes come from a file dictionary (each line being formatted `"regex": type` e.g. `"(\t*for.*in.*?:.?)": for` And also the program uses only one capture group. It should thus be possible to run `re.sub()` twice, and mark e.g. all `for` first and all `in` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use capturing and backreferences:

```
^(\t*)(for\b)(.*)\b(in)\b(.*?:)
```

Replace  with `$1<color>$2</color>$3<color>$4</color>$5`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s1zOvo/1).

Here, the expression is split into 5 subparts with `(...)` capturing groups. In the replacement pattern, those values captured are referred to with backreferences having `$`+`n` format where `n` is the ID of the capturing group inside the pattern.

If you have no chance to run 1 regex with multiple capturing groups, run two on end:

- `^(\t*)for\b(?=.*\bin\b.*?:)` --> `$1<color>for</color>` (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/dICTGp/1))
- `^(\t*for\b.*)\bin\b(?=.*?:)` --> `$1<color>in</color>` (see [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dICTGp/2)).

The single capturing group is around the part before the word, and the part after the word is not matched but checked with a positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
import re

STR = """
for i in iterations:
    pass
"""

pattern = r'(\b)(for|in|pass)(\b)'
change = r'\1<COLOR>\2</COLOR>\3'

print re.sub(pattern, change, STR)
```

so I'm capturing the keywords with whitespaces and give them back with as \1 and \3

this gives:

```
<COLOR>for</COLOR> i <COLOR>in</COLOR> iterations:
    <COLOR>pass</COLOR>
```